# How to verify the hostname obtained by resolving IP is the correct one

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, networking, winsock

I am very much new to network programming and maybe I am asking a very basic question.

I am working on a legacy C++ codebase where the windows *'getnameinfo'* API is used to obtain the hostname from the given IP address. The obtained hostname is wrong and it belongs to a different VM in the domain.

Let us say, there is VM with hostname 'VM1' with IP 10.44.176.57 and
another VM with hostname 'VM2' and IP 10.44.176.24.

When IP  10.44.176.57 is passed to the getnameinfo() API, it resolves it to the hostname VM2.
The ping command also returns the same results.

When I ping hostname VM1 and VM2 both resolves to their correct respective IP addresses.

I checked in DNS manager, the IPs of VMs are assigned correctly.
My question is,
1) Why getnameinfo API is returning the wrong hostname?
2) Is there any way to verify the resolved hostname is the correct one ?

Comment: Are these IP addresses allocated over DHCP?  Or manually set on the VM itself. My guess is that there's some fair amount of recycling of hostnames and IP addresses between these different VMs.

Comment: > Why getnameinfo API is returning the wrong hostname?

Essentially because that's the hostname the VM you run that code on sees for that IP.

What kind of VM software are you using? 

What is the host operating system?

What is the guest operating system?

What is the VM guest/host network configuration for that VM?

Are you able to provide a simple way to reproduce your issue? A snippet of code and steps to reproduce, perhaps?

> Is there any way to verify the resolved hostname is the correct one?

Use a shell on the same VM to ping the resolved hostname.